# ggplot facet wrap got decimals in y axis instead of integers

Tags: r, ggplot2

Got decimals instead of integers for y-axis values in one of two plots gotten with facet wrap and free scales.

I verified the numbers in the data frame and they are correct. I tried with facet grid and got the same thing. I also tried with scale_y_conitnuos but the number range is different for both graphics. I also tried two graphics and put both together with ggarrange, but there are two y_axis labels. I would like only one shared y_axis label. With the code below I got the desired result, except for the decimals in y_axis.

```
   DATA <- tibble(
color = c( "blue","blue","blue","white","white","white","white",
    "white","white","white","red","red","red","red","red",
    "purple","purple","purple","purple","purple","purple",
    "black","black","black","black","black","black"), 
freq  = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,13, 6, 3, 1, 3,15,
     1,10, 6, 1, 2,13, 1, 5, 3, 1),
max = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3, 8, 2, 9, 6,11, 4, 3, 9,
     2, 5, 4, 4, 4,10, 3, 2, 3, 2), 
code = c("A","E","B","A","E","D","B","F","C","G","A","E","B",
    "F","G","A","E","D","B","F","G","A","E","H","B","F","G"),
group = c("a)","b)","a)","a)","b)","a)","a)","b)","a)","b)","a)","b)"
    ,"a)","b)","b)","a)","b)","a)","a)","b)","b)","a)","b)","b)","a)","b)","b)")
)
```

```
ggplot(DATA, aes(x= code, y=freq,fill=color))+                                                                                           

facet_wrap(~group, nrow = 2, scales = "free") +
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", color = "black", 
fill = NA,  linetype = "dashed",
       size = 0.3,
       aes(group = color, y = max)) +

labs(y="Frequency",x= "Design")
```

I would like to get integers in both plots with free scales and only one y_axis label. Decimals are not adequate.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `scales = "free_x"` option in `facet_wrap`

You can get the plot you want.

```
 facet_wrap(~group, nrow = 2, scales = "free_x")
```

Full code below :

```
ggplot(DATA, aes(x= code, y=freq,fill=color))+
  facet_wrap(~group, nrow = 2, scales = "free_x",) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", color = "black", 
           fill = NA,  linetype = "dashed",
           size = 0.3,
           aes(group = color, y = max)) +
  labs(y="Frequency",x= "Design")
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Sorry i added wrong plot .. so i edited just before !!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, but I would like to have proportional axis_y for every plot, with a maximum frequency of 10 in the first plot and 15 in the second. Maybe, in this plot, the difference is not big, but I have other plots with free scales which maximum values are very different between faceted plots, so I would like to keep the same format. And, in this case, I am talking about individuals, so integers are the appropriate way to show it.